# New iMac freezing every click

Tags: hard-drive, imac, performance

I bought this iMac 6 months ago, model late2019, with 64gb RAM and fusion HD 3TB

I ran all the utility tool and I get a lot of MT mapping warnings when i run the First Aid, but they don't seem to be critical error

I feel my computer started to get slower/freeze after a message about Adobe Creative cloud file being corrupted or what not... was an unusual message but i just ignored it until the mac was impossible to use, literally freezing for a minute every click.

I wonder if installing bigSur will fix everything or should I simply erase everything and reinstall the original OS, then upgrade to bigsur and reinstall all the apps (pain in the butt:))

thanks

Comment: Can you add the results of the terminal commands `diskutil list` & `diskutil cs list` to your question - select after paste & hit Ctrl/K (not Cmd, Ctrl) to format it correctly. I've a vague suspicion the SSD has failed or the CoreStorage is broken.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: **Always** backup your files!

---

I would start narrowing down the issue, i.e. trying to find the actual cause.

- Run `First Aid` **multiple** times on your hard drive and see if it is able to repair the disk. You should also try running it in recovery mode.
- *Save your data before doing this*: Uninstall the Adobe Creative cloud completely and delete all Adobe files. If this solves the problem, copy one file at a time back onto your iMac. By doing so, you should be able to tell which file may be causing issues.
- *Not clear from the question* Check if certain programs slow down the machine, e.g. the Adobe Creative Cloud or something else in the background. You can check current processes in the `Activity Monitor` app.
- Reset SMC and NVRAM/PRAM
- Check if the problems persist in safe mode
- (run Apple hardware test)

Check the [different startup modes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255).

Making a clean install (preferably with an USB installer) is always an option, but will only solve software issues and should not be needed after 6 months.